# VSTS release only logs the 1st line of a Powershell exception as an error. How can I log the full exception details without enabling debug?

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

If I run this code (containing a null reference) in Powershell ISE

```
$result = $nonExistentString.Substring(0,4)
```

An exception is thrown and the following is output to the console

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $result = $nonExistentString.Substring(0,4)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

However, if I run the same code in a VSTS release as a powershell inline script, the release log will only output the following :

```
2017-11-30T13:23:26.9471504Z ##[error]You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

This isn't enough detail to facilitate problem resolution in more complex scripts. I know I can run the scripts in debug mode and the full exception record is logged as debug entries, but this would mean we would need to run all scripts in debug at all times in order to get full exception details when they occur. Does anyone know if it possible to configure VSTS to log full exception details without having to enable debug?

Comment: VSTS release log shows the same error as you execute in Powershell ISE. The messages `+ $result = $nonExistentString.Substring(0,4)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull` should show in the following of `2017-11-30T13:23:26.9471504Z ##[error]You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression`.